# After recent upgrade, nvidia card cannot be detected

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

After recent upgrade from 346.59 to 346.72, my nvidia card can no longer be detected. Any one got suggestions on how to further troubleshoot on this one?

My last good reboot was around 5/22. After that, I did an update, I will list the packages at the bottom of my question.

Trying to fallback and use 331:
purge nvidia*

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-331* nvidia-331-uvm* nvidia-346* nvidia-libopencl1-331*
  nvidia-opencl-icd-331* nvidia-opencl-icd-346* nvidia-prime* nvidia-settings*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 214 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 419173 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-opencl-icd-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-opencl-icd-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Removing nvidia-libopencl1-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-libopencl1-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Removing nvidia-331-uvm (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Removing nvidia-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
INFO:Disable nvidia-331
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
stop: Unknown instance: 
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Purging configuration files for nvidia-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-346 (346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-346 (346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2) ...
Removing nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
Removing nvidia-settings (331.20-0ubuntu8) ...
Purging configuration files for nvidia-settings (331.20-0ubuntu8) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
```

sudo apt-get install nvidia-331

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-libopencl1-331 nvidia-opencl-icd-331 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-331 nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-libopencl1-331 nvidia-opencl-icd-331
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/45.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 214 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-331.
(Reading database ... 418848 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-331_331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-331-uvm.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-331-uvm_331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-331-uvm (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-libopencl1-331.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-libopencl1-331_331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-libopencl1-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-opencl-icd-331.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-331_331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-prime_0.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-settings_331.20-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (331.20-0ubuntu8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-331/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
INFO:Enable nvidia-331
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 118) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 128) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 118) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/'.
Loading new nvidia-331-331.113 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-38-generic
Done.

nvidia_331:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.16.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
nvidia-prime start/running, process 15277
Setting up nvidia-settings (331.20-0ubuntu8) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up nvidia-331-uvm (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Loading new nvidia-331-uvm-331.113 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-38-generic
Done.

nvidia-331-uvm:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.16.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-libopencl1-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-331 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

Here's some more details and what I have tried (1st try):
System : 14.04.2 x64

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13c2 (rev a1)

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia               8379692  0 
drm                   311018  6 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia

$ modprobe -R nvidia
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
$ modprobe -R nvidia-346
nvidia_346
$ modprobe -R nvidia_346
nvidia_346

/var/log/Xorg
[     2.353] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     2.353] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.353]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.917
[     2.353]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.353]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[     2.353] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     2.354] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[     2.354] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     2.354] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     2.354] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

dmesg | grep -i nvidia
[    1.504413] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.508557] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.700061] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    1.700069] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  346.72  Tue May  5 22:03:13 PDT 2015
[    2.195448] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[    2.195527] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
[    2.195601] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
[    2.195685] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
[    2.219277] init: nvidia-prime main process (1172) terminated with status 127


I've tried,
1) purge all nvidia-* and do apt-get autoremove, and re-install nvidia-346

2) downgrade my ubuntu-drivers-common to 0.2.91.9 ( Didn't seeme to help)




Packages installed ( through update ) on 5/22
Install: libjansson4:amd64 (2.5-2), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (352.09-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1)
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 (1.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), fuse:amd64 (2.9.2-4ubuntu4, 2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1), virtualbox:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu4, 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5), libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), nvidia-settings:amd64 (346.47-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1, 352.09-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libcuda1-346:amd64 (346.59-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1, 346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2), libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libglapi-mesa:i386 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), nvidia-346:amd64 (346.59-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1, 346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2), virtualbox-dkms:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu4, 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5), libgles2-mesa:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), liboxideqtcore0:amd64 (1.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), libxatracker2:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), virtualbox-qt:amd64 (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu4, 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2.99.917+git20150505.5054e227-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty, 2.99.917+git20150521.e617c194-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), nvidia-opencl-icd-346:amd64 (346.59-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1, 346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), nvidia-346-uvm:amd64 (346.59-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1, 346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2), libgbm1:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11), liboxideqtquick0:amd64 (1.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), nvidia-346-dev:amd64 (346.59-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1, 346.72-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.2), apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11), liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 (1.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.7.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), mesa-common-dev:amd64 (10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty, 10.6.0~git20150521+10.6.7c5cca5e-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty), python3-apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-53.88, 3.13.0-53.89), libfuse2:amd64 (2.9.2-4ubuntu4, 2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty, 2.4.61+git20150521.e9ea1f42-0ubuntu0ricotz2~trusty)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` is used. On updates you install unstable packages. It is possible to install nvidia drivers from there, but it is not recommended to leave that ppa always connected.

You can fix this by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

This will remove that ppa and revert packages to stable ones.

And you have hybrid graphics with Intel. Consder installing nvidia-prime too.

Comment: I followed and purged the xorg-edgers stuff. And I tried to install the nvidia-331 ( instead of 346 from the egders ). But I am still running into the similiar issues, the system is not detecting the nvidia card.

Comment: Here's what I did, 1) purged ppa, 2) rebooted 3) install nvidia-331 ( nvidia prime has always been there ) 4) rebooted, but I still see the modprobe nvidia FATAL. and similar Xorg messages / dmesg

Comment: Does the system boot without a proprietary driver? And it looks like nvidia doe not build. What is your kernel version?

Comment: The kernel version is 3.16.0-38.   The system right now is booting, but I have to have my monitor connected through intel's display port ( It's a desktop and nvidia card is for the enhanced 3d and other purposes . )

Comment: Please do `sudo purge nvidia*` and then run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331` and add output to your post.

Comment: Just did. sorry it took a while to get used to the formatting

Comment: I do not have a good answer, sry. Maybe try to install nvidia-349 from xorg-edgers, but after that run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` not to upgrade from there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all I could.
But none really worked. (331 / 304 (the current) from stable and 346 / 349 / 352 from xorg-edgers/ppa )

Eventually I just gave up and installed the .run driver downloaded from nvidia.

Hope this info helps for people who also had the similar issue.

*will try to do a clean installation in the future to find out more

Comment: Did it work (the `.run` driver downloaded from NVIDIA)? I didn't get this from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if running kernel is older than that was recently updated. Ensure that version of the kernel where the driver modules were installed is the same as of running kernel. If not then set the new kernel as bootable.